# Exporting Cinema 4D to .png - remove thick lines around the poly/

Tags: 3d, cinema4d

On my screen in cinema 4D I see this - 
[image]

Which is the low poly effect I want.

But when I render it in the picture viewer and exported result, looks like this -
[image: End result]

Is there a setting to turn the lines off?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the fact that you applied a sketch toon material and enabled the sketch toon render option in the render setting.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Try to uncheck this one]

Try to uncheck «Sketch and Toon» in your Render Settings.